# How do I update Android SDK in Linux via command line

Tags: android

Is there a ubuntu commandline command to update my Android API, I need to download android-19

Note: I am using ubuntu commandline only, no GUI.

Thanks,

Comment: try this [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK#Downloading_the_SDK_Starter_Package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK#Downloading_the_SDK_Starter_Package)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/recent/updatingsdkfromcommand-line):

> Starting with Tools R12, the SDK Manager offers a slightly better way
>   to update the SDK from command-line.
>
> Previously the "`android update sdk --no-ui`" command already allowed
>   one to update from the command-line, but it had the annoying tendency
>   of installing every single platform or add-on. There are now 30 or
>   more packages available on the SDK repository, including 12 platforms;
>   that's a lot to download when most people only need the most recent
>   platform. Starting with R12, you can use combine new things:
>
> - "`android list sdk`" will connect to the remote repository and list all the
>     packages available with an index number.
> - "`android update sdk --no-ui`"
>     accepts a "`--filter`" argument that can take a package index, or a
>     category name.
>
> Here's an example in action:
>
> [image]
>
> There's still room for improvement, notably in a future release we'll work on the first install case and making the update smarter at figuring out what to get.

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk   I want to download the category "Android 6.0" but it won't work when I write "android update sdk --no-ui --filter Android 6.0". Are you aware of the command that could do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can make use of

`     android list sdk --extended`

This should give you more details on what is the filter you should be using. For Android 6.0 in my setup it is showing as 

`    id: 32 or "android-23"
         Type: Platform
         Desc: Android SDK Platform 23
              Revision 3
`
To install you would then do this

    `android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-23"`

Comment: Command is now obsolete. You can use "android update sdk --use-sdk-wrapper"

Answer (score 5):

Since the `android` command is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android)
you should use the `sdkmanager` command
([here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager))

Go to `< Android Sdk dir >/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` and run `./sdkmanager --update`. This will update all packages to the latest version.

Note: `< Android Sdk dir >` is usually `~/Android/Sdk`

To find the available packages

- `./sdkmanager --list`

Then once you know which package you want to install (for example API 30)

- `./sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-30"`